# Facebook Check-in with graph API 3.0

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

/check-in has been [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/checkin) and replaced by [feed posting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/feed)

Now, the `publish_actions` permission needed for checking in to a place using its placeId is also deprecated and will not be supported after August 1st.

The only way I have found to add check-in functionality to my app is by using [Facebook share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), but I can't find a way to set my PlaceId so it is a lot less likely user will select my place to check-in.

It is impossible to find an alternative for checking in to a specific location and Facebook is not being very helpful about it. It seems to me like the check in functionality is getting removed altogether, but I cant find an official quote or an explicit statement that the check in functionality is changing. It is only implied by deprecating the tools needed for it to work

Am I missing something? How are we supposed to check in to a specific location using its placeId in graph 3.0?

As far as I can tell, this concerns iOS and Android and related dev technologies and plug-ins, so I wont post any code. Please comment if you see a reason why code would be helpful.

Comment: Don’t think there currently is a way, at least not one that allows to specify the place upfront. (Not too sad about it either though; I have hardly ever seen a check-in/post with location attached _posted through a 3rd-party app_ show up in my feed, that I would not classify as spam …)

Comment: @CBroe I see what you mean, but this way my check-in feature is nothing more than a FB status posting feature... I'm getting around it by setting the FB place URL as share dialog href